# Problems with More than 1 Left joins in MSAccess

Tags: sql, ms-access

This is related to my previous question [More than 1 Left joins in MSAccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057167/more-than-1-left-joins-in-msaccess)

The problem is that I have 3 left joins followed by an `AND` operator to check 1 condition.

If I run, then I am getting an error *"Join Expression not supported"*.

The query goes like this:

```
SELECT * FROM(( EMPLOYEE AS E  LEFT JOIN DEPARTMENT AS D ON E.EID=D.EID)
                 LEFT JOIN MANAGERS M ON D.DID=M.DID)
             LEFT JOIN MANAGERDETAILS MD  ON M.MDID=MD.MDID
 **AND E.ENO=MD.ENO**
```

If I take out `AND` part, it works fine.

Any idea?

Comment: Are you writing your join by hand or are you letting the QBE write it for you? I find that it works better to let the QBE do it.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but multiple LEFT JOIN aren't properly supported in the QBE since you can't really set the order in which the joins are operated. I find that multiple joins tend to end-up in a mess and rarely give me what I expect.
I usually always resort to SQL for more complex queries, gives me more control over the way the query is constructed.

Comment: This query isn't that complicated. Use the QBE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I would write this would be:

```
SELECT EDM.*, MANAGERDETAILS.*
FROM (
    SELECT ED.*, MANAGERS.*
    FROM (
        SELECT EMPLOYEE.*, DEPARTMENT.*
        FROM EMPLOYEE
        LEFT JOIN DEPARTMENT
        ON EMPLOYEE.EID = DEPARTMENT.EID
    ) AS ED
    LEFT JOIN MANAGERS
    ON ED.DID = MANAGERS.DID
) AS EDM
LEFT JOIN MANAGERDETAILS
ON EDM.MDID = MANAGERDETAILS.MDID
    AND EDM.ENO = MANAGERDETAILS.ENO
```

Basically, you join tables one at a time and alias the result that you can then use for the next join.

You can achieve arbitrarily complex Left joins in Access only by aliasing smaller subsets.
Your double join clause probably doesn't work because one of its members refers to a deeper resultset than the one that's visible at that level of the query.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to match two fileds in the ON clause and any of the tables is MANAGERDETAILS.

I don't know what you are trying to get with this sql but you can either put the AND filter on the correct ON (after E.EID = D.EID) or you can change the tables used to filter in the current ON so one of the fields belongs to MANAGERDETAILS.

Comment: Do you mean

SELECT * FROM(( ( EMPLOYEE AS E LEFT JOIN DEPARTMENT AS D ON E.EID=D.EID) LEFT JOIN MANAGERS M ON D.DID=M.DID) LEFT JOIN MANAGERDETAILS MD ON M.MDID=MD.MDID ) AND E.ENO=D.ENO

In that case also it is throwing error.

Could you please rewrite the above query. 

Don't worry about the result.

Comment: This is what I meant:

SELECT * FROM(( ( EMPLOYEE AS E LEFT JOIN DEPARTMENT AS D ON E.EID=D.EID AND E.ENO=D.ENO) LEFT JOIN MANAGERS M ON D.DID=M.DID) LEFT JOIN MANAGERDETAILS MD ON M.MDID=MD.MDID )

Answer (score 0):

You need a second reference to the Employee table since you are trying to pull the manager's employee record.

SELECT *
FROM 
(
  (
    (EMPLOYEE AS E LEFT JOIN DEPARTMENT AS D ON E.EID = D.EID) 
    LEFT JOIN MANAGERS AS M 
      ON D.DID = M.DID
  ) 
LEFT JOIN MANAGERDETAILS AS MD 
  ON M.DID = MD.MDID
) 
LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE AS E2 ON MD.ENO = E2.ENO;

We don't have enough information on the data you expect, but this query will execute.

I know in Access you'll need to handle the parentheses, but you could do this with the graphic query builder.

Comment: This will not work because if you want to perform more than one left join in MS Access, you should use parenthesis in the From clause

Comment: I guess that explains the "I know in Access you'll need to handle the parentheses.." part.