# How to create a query to get all records from one table and fill in field information from a second table with a where statement?

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I have two tables. One is called *prem* and contains all ids that exist in a system, and *JimsQueryByColl* which has most of those ids with various information attached. I am trying to create a single query that will include all of the ids from prem, and all of the records from the *JimsQueryByColl* where *JimsQueryByColl.Collector = "Frederick Road"*. The current query I have is as follows but only gives the latter part of the information (without the ids from the prem that don't appear in a list of ids with Frederick Road in the collector collumn):

> SELECT Prem.meter_miu_id,
>   JimsQueryByColl.*, Prem.longitude,
>   Prem.latitude
>   FROM Prem LEFT JOIN
>   JimsQueryByColl ON Prem.meter_miu_id =
>   JimsQueryByColl.[MIU ID]
>   WHERE
>   (((JimsQueryByColl.Collector)="Frederick
>   Road"))

Normally the Left Join would have achieved what i desire but the where statement is making it where the ids that would have blank information for all but the *Prem.meter_miu_id* field are not included. I have tried to add an "*or JimsQueryByColl.Collector IS NULL*" to the WHERE statement but that didn't get the correct result.

The current two query method I have for getting the right information are titled FredrickRoad and Query3:

FredrickRoad-

> SELECT  JimsQueryByColl.* FROM
>   JimsQueryByColl  WHERE
>   (((JimsQueryByColl.Collector)="Frederick
>   Road"))

Followed by Query3 -

> SELECT Prem.meter_miu_id,
>   JimsQueryByColl.*, Prem.longitude,
>   Prem.latitude FROM Prem LEFT JOIN
>   JimsQueryByColl ON Prem.meter_miu_id =
>   JimsQueryByColl.[MIU ID] WHERE
>   (((JimsQueryByColl.Collector)="Frederick
>   Road"));

But I would like to do this in one step if possible. I hope I have written this clearly and if someone needs clarification just ask.

**Current Solution**

> SELECT Prem.meter_miu_id,
>   JimsQueryByColl.*, Prem.longitude,
>   Prem.latitude
>   Into FrederickRoad
>   FROM Prem LEFT JOIN
>   JimsQueryByColl  ON (Prem.meter_miu_id
>   = JimsQueryByColl.[MIU ID]
>   AND JimsQueryByColl.Collector="Frederick
>   Road")

This gets around the odd bug/error I'm getting with the query since it puts it into a table and doesn't deal with the query directly again. I would however love to know what is causing the problems I'm having.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT Prem.meter_miu_id, JimsQueryByColl.*, Prem.longitude, Prem.latitude
FROM Prem LEFT JOIN JimsQueryByColl 
ON (Prem.meter_miu_id = JimsQueryByColl.[MIU ID] 
AND JimsQueryByColl.Collector="Frederick Road")
```

Comment: This isn't working for me, it seems like the AND in the join statement isn't supported by Access 2007

Comment: Got it to work. All I had to do was surround "Prem.meter_miu_id = JimsQueryByColl.[MIU ID] 
AND JimsQueryByColl.Collector="Frederick Road""
 with parentheses. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Actually, this kind of works and kind of doesn't. I can trick Access into doing this once but when I try to close it and run it again it still gives me the "Join expression not supported" error and won't open the query at all. Any idea how to make this work in Access?

Comment: By putting parentheses around the On statement like you have shown but when I close Access and open it back up and try to open the query, even in design view, it gives me that error. And even when I can get it to run the first time I enter the sql, it gives me that error if I try to sort the result by the Prem.meter_miu_id. I have no answer for how it is giving me the correct result and then telling me that the join statement isn't support. It doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Can you put the exact statement you are trying - you just mentioned you added an 'order by' statement. There is no reason the 'exact' same query would work one second, and not work the next second.

Comment: LEFT JOINs are definitely supported: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208894(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: yes, Left Joins are supported. It is probably the AND in the join statement that is causing problems. And I have not added an order by statement. I am using the same query that is in this answer with the parentheses around the On statement: SELECT Prem.meter_miu_id, JimsQueryByColl.*, Prem.longitude, Prem.latitude
FROM Prem LEFT JOIN JimsQueryByColl 
ON (Prem.meter_miu_id = JimsQueryByColl.[MIU ID] 
AND JimsQueryByColl.Collector="Frederick Road"). The sorting I was refering to is when I click on the column name after the results are given to make that column ascending or descending sort.

Comment: check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057627/problems-with-more-than-1-left-joins-in-msaccess - it shows a left join in access with an 'AND' operator, so that ain't it :) - I'm not sure what else is going on to cause the issues you are having....

Comment: Also, check if access is inadvertently adding 'OUTER' keyword to the LEFT JOIN, which is not jet sql syntax, and won't work.. for reference: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/creating-an-outer-join-query-in-access-HA001034555.aspx

Comment: Access does not add "OUTER" to any joins, as it doesn't understand what it means. Indeed, you can right SQL with it, and Access will entirely ignore it (and remove it entirely when you save the query, in fact).

Comment: The join type is supported, but it can't be represented in the QBE's design view. You have to edit SQL statements with these kinds of JOINs in the SQL view only.

Comment: Also, when I try to run the query without the parentheses around the on statement, as shown in the answer, it doesn't run the query and Highlights "JimsQueryByColl.Collector="Frederick Road"" as the source of the problem. To reiterate, I can get the query to run with the parentheses but if I try to click on the meter_miu_id column to sort by ascending or descending order it gives me the "Join not supported" error again as well as sometimes when I close everything and try to reopen the query it gives me the same error and refuses to open it. In short this solution works temporarily but not

Comment: permanently and the bug might be in access not the sql, I can't tell.